# php text line by line not working

Tags: php

I have a text file called things.txt with:

```
thing1
thing2
thing34
```

and php:

```
$fp = fopen('things.txt');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    echo $line."<br>";
}
fclose($fp);
```

and it's not working...any ideas?

Comment: any errormessage or just wrong output?

Comment: it just loops forever.  how can I make it show an error message?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) is your friend...

Comment: `error_reporting(-1)` is your other friend...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) *requires* at least *two* parameters!

```
$fp = fopen('things.txt', 'r');
```

The second one is the mode. `r` ("readonly, pointer at the beginning, no truncate") should work fine here, because you only read it. For the other modes, refer the manual (linked above).

You should change your development settings to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

because you should get an error for this. However, the reason for the infinite loop is, that `fopen()` returns `null` and `feof(null)` returns `false` and `while(!false)` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

try `$fp = fopen('things.txt', 'r') or die('unable to open file');` to see if your script can actually find your file

Answer (score 2):

When using fopen, you need to specify a mode (reading, writing, etc). So you should change your code to:

```
$fp = fopen('things.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp);
    echo $line."<br>";
}
fclose($fp);
```